# MSSQL Insert takes over 5 hours, when inserting more than specific number of rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a question connected with MS SQL. When inserting less then about 1350000 rows to the table it all takes about 2 minutes, but when number of inserted rows is bigger, then a time needed to insert data grows to about 5 hours.

The problem is not connected with query or indexes, because everything has been working fine for a long time and nothing has changed in the structure of query, tables or indexes. Problem appeared for the first time about 2 weeks ago and it appears repeatedly on days, when number of inserted rows is bigger than +-1350000. For example on one day number of ins rows is 1200000 and the process takes 2 minutes, on the other day number of rows is 1450000 and it takes 5-6 hours to insert data.

I tried to rebuild indexes, but it has not helped.

:)